# return const reference vs temporary object

Tags: c++, reference, constants

I'm wondering why returning `const reference` of a local object is illegal whereas returning a `local object` is legal as long as you assign it to a `const reference`?

```
vector<int> f_legal() {
    vector<int> tempVec;
    tempVec.push_back(1);
    return tempVec;
}

const vector<int>& f_illegal() {
    vector<int> tempVec;
    tempVec.push_back(1);
    return tempVec;
}

void g() {
    const vector<int>& v1 = f_legal(); // legal
    const vector<int>& v2 = f_illegal(); // illegal
}
```

Edit:
My point is that if assigning a const ref to a returned local variable is legal, then shouldn't assigning a const ref to a returned const ref of a local variable be legal as well?

Comment: @Ed Heal Yes it's well-defined in C++ that a local const reference will extend the lifetime of a temporary to which it is bound.

Comment: @EdHeal yes, it's legal. There's a special case in the standard that will keep a local object alive as long as there's a const reference to it in the current scope.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Even if you assign it to a const reference, the return value is declared as passed by value, that means it'll be copied<sup>[1]</sup> to outside as a temporary object, and then binded to the const reference. Binding temporary object to a *const* reference is fine, the object won't be destroyed until getting out of the lifetime of the const reference.

On the other hand, returning reference of a local variable is illegel. The local variable'll be destroyed when the function returned, that means the outside reference will be dangled.

**EDIT**

> My point is that if assigning a const ref to a returned local variable is legal, then shouldn't assigning a const ref to a returned const ref of a local variable be legal as well?

The point is the 1st case is not assigning a const ref to a returned *local variable*, it's assigning a const ref to a returned *temporary variable*. (Which might copied from the local variable.)

---

<sup><sup>[1]</sup> The copy might be omitted according to RVO technically.</sup>

Comment: Are you sure that is always the case? Even considering `RVO/NRVO`?

Comment: @JamesAdkison: There will be a temporary object, and the reference will bind to that temporary.  The copy might be elided (if the result can be constructed directly in the temporary).

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, that was my point (i.e., the copy could be elided).

Comment: @JamesAdkison afaik RVO as an optimization does not change any of the rules. The "rule" is: return value is passed by value (i.e. copied)

Comment: Isn't the question *why* this is the case?

Comment: @tobi303 Yes, it doesn't change any rule regarding the lifetime of the object. I was just pointing out that a copy does not necessarily occur.

Comment: @JamesAdkison actually now I think what I wrote is non-sense. Isnt it the case, that RVO is this expception where an optimization may alter the program flow (i.e. any side effects of the copy)

Answer (score 15):

Returning a reference to a local variable is illegal (Undefined Behavior). Period. There is no `const` or `mutable` clause.

This is because local function variables have automatic storage duration. They are "destroyed" after the function exits. If the function returns a reference to such a variable, that reference it is said to be dangling: it refers to an object that no longer exists.

The first one is legal because of a special C++ rule: initializing a reference to a `prvalue` extends the lifetime of that temporary object to the lifetime of the reference.

Comment: The rule actually has nothing to do with `const` -- any reference which is *directly* bound to a temporary extends the lifetime of that temporary.  In C++98, other rules provided that only const references could directly bind to a temporary, those rules have now changed, which had a domino effect on the lifetime extension rule.

Comment: @BenVoigt That's the first I hear of this. Could you provide a reference?

Comment: @BenVoigt Thank you. It was most helpful.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yet `int& r = 3;` does not compile in C++ 17, while `const int& r = 3;` does. Why?

Comment: @Maggyero please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52104874/2805305

Comment: BenVoigt said "The rule actually has nothing to do with `const`" But in my example `const` has an influence, so this sentence is incorrect. If "any reference which is *directly* bound to a temporary extends the lifetime of that temporary.", how do you explain that `int& r = 3;` does not compile?

Comment: @Maggyero: That is not a reference directly bound to a temporary, it is a compile error.  But `int&& r = 3;` does compile, and does extend the lifetime of the temporary.

Comment: @BenVoigt Okay I see your point. But this compile error occurs when using a non-`const` lvalue reference, so saying that "The rule actually has nothing to do with `const`" might be a bit misleading.

Comment: @Maggyero it's a different error. You can't bind a non-const reference to a temporary. We are talking about extending the life of a temporary with a reference. Any reference that you bind to a temporary extends the lifetime of that temporary.

Comment: "You can't bind a non-const reference to a temporary" In this case I would rather say "Any reference that you **can** bind to a temporary extends the lifetime of that temporary." Otherwise the reader might think that all references can be bind.

Comment: @Maggyero: You also can get reference binding compile errors from type mismatches, or other qualifier mismatches like trying to remove volatile without `const_cast`.  If I say that a reference *is* directly bound, then naturally it must follow that I am only talking about scenarios where it is possible.

Comment: and btw the comment you have a problem with says "any reference which is directly bound to a temporary extends the lifetime of that temporary" which is more very clear.

Comment: @BenVoigt Seing "nothing to do with `const`" and "any reference" in the same sentence can lead to the interpretation that any type of reference, `const` or not, can bind. At least that is how I interpreted it. That was not even clear for @bolov himself: "That's the first I hear of this. Could you provide a reference?" But now that you have clarified there is no more ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely because it would totally ruin the whole stack based calling conventions that have served us well for decades...that pretty much every CPU assumes.