# C++11 rvalue reference vs const reference

Tags: c++, c++11

This may be obvious but I think it is something difficult to me. Given this:

```
void test(std::string&&) { }

std::string x{"test"};
test(std::move(x)); // ok
```

This code calls `test()`  with a rvalue reference as parameter so the program compiles as I expect.

Now look at this:

```
void other_test(const std::string&) { }

std::string x{"test"};
other_test(std::move(x)); // ok???
```

And here I'm tilted.  Why does this version compile? The `std::move` returns a && type; why then I don't get an error in the second method where I use `const&`?

---

I know that

```
int&& s = 5;
const int& s = 5;
```

is valid because in both cases I provide something that has not an lvalue, it has no addresses. Are `&&` and `const&` equivalent? If no, are there differences?

Comment: I cannot understand why const& and && behave in the same way. What is the difference? I expected that the const& version would fail and not print the text

Comment: I expect an error! From my understanding a move should return an && type and so only an && parameter should work. Why then a const& parameter works?

Comment: " Why then a const& parameter works?" because rvalue reference can be converted to const reference.

Comment: Is the question "Why can a `const&` bind to an rvalue when I expect it to fail?"

Comment: @Barry yes that is the question

Comment: I think some clarification is needed. Are `void test(std::string&& a)` and `void test(const std::string& a)` _both_ in scope when you do your tests?

Comment: Your added code will fail to compile when you comment first function and uncomment second

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`std::move` doesn't actually move anything out of it's own. It's just a fancy name for a cast to a `T&&`. Calling `test` like this `test(std::move(x));` only shows that a `T&&` is implicitly convertible to a `const T&`. The compiler sees that `test` only accepts `const T&` so it converts the `T&&` returned from `std::move` to a `const T&`, that's all there is to it.

Comment: Ok thank you! Now I'd have another question, Why should I declare the paremeter as && when I have const&?

Comment: @EmmaRossignoli Because you can't modify an object through a const reference.  The point of of using rvalue references and move semantics is to modify the object by stealing its resources.

Comment: @EmmaRossignoli If you declare it as `T&&` then you're saying "`test` should only accept an rvalue-reference". It doesn't say anything or impose any requirements on the caller when it comes to how the caller got that rvalue-ref.

Comment: @EmmaRossignoli Read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics/11540204#11540204 and understand it it is all explained there

Comment: Now I understand that && can be converted to const& but the difference is that a const& cannot be edited (of course due to the const) while the && yes. My doubt is solved thank you all

Comment: @EmmaRossignoli It's by no means "obvious"

Comment: @EmmaRossignoli And if we're going to be picky, there's no conversion here at all. It's just that a lvalue reference to const can bind to anything, but an rvalue reference can only bind to an rvalue.

Comment: @EmmaRossignoli Exactly. A good example is constructors. A `T&&` should always be implicitly convertible to a `const T&` so the copy constructor can act as a backup when the move constructor is disabled/deleted.

Comment: @Barry I think this isn't the time to be picky

Comment: @Barry Is that a chicken joke?

Comment: @Barry Fair enough, I agree with you there. I suppose I worded it incorrectly. What I meant was that information overload in a short time span can be bad.

Comment: I get what SombreroChicken said. I thank you @Barry for the comment but I will read again your sentence in a second moment, now I'm learning this and I need easy terms

Comment: Also note that you can also pass both lvalue ref/rvalue ref to the const lvalue ref.

Comment: When you said `test` and `test(std::move(x));` in the answer, do you mean `other_test` in the 2nd code snippet of the question?

Answer (score 18):

In simple terms:

- `&&` can bind to non-const rvalues (prvalues and xvalues)
- `const &&` can bind to rvalues (const and non-const)
- `&` can bind to non-const lvalues
- `const &` can bind to rvalues  (prvalues and xvalues) and lvalues (const and non-const for each). A.k.a. to anything.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a function to expressly allow const-Lvalue objects, but expressly disallow Rvalue objects, write the function signature like this:

```
void test(const std::string&) { }
void test(std::string&&) = delete;//Will now be considered when matching signatures

int main() {
    std::string string = "test";
    test(string);//OK
    //test(std::move(string));//Compile Error!
    //test("Test2");//Compile Error!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> test(std::string&& a) {
>   something(a) //--> not moved because it has lvalue
> ```

Names of variables are lvalues. `a` is a name of a variable, therefore `a` **is** an lvalue expression, and therefore it will not be moved from.

It's unclear what you mean by "has". `a` is an expression. It is a name of a reference, and references refer to objects. Value categories pertain to expressions, not objects.

> `test(const std::string& a)`: a is const lvalue reference and like before I have lvalue and rvalue. And plus more, in this case if I called
>
> ```
> std::move(a)
> ```
>
> where a is a const& the move works!

If by "works" you mean that it invokes a move constructor or assignment, then no, it does not work because no move construction or assignment has happened.

Comment: There is no temporary object. `std::move(x)` is an xvalue, thus a glvalue.

Comment: @xskxzr I removed that part of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `std::move(x)`, an `rvalue` reference to the underlying data, `test`, will be returned.  You are allowed to pass `rvalue` references as `const` **(and const only!)** reference parameters because an **`rvalue` reference is implicitly convertible to a `const` reference.**  They are arguably the same thing from the function's point of view (a read only parameter).  If you removed the const-qualifier of your parameter, this code would not compile:

```
void other_test(std::string&) { }
std::string x{"test"};
other_test(std::move(x)); //not okay because
//the function can potentially modify the parameter.
```

See [Bo Qian's youtube video on rvalue vs lvalue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTUdhjzws5g).